# Null value in CSV with Bash

Tags: bash, csv

I am trying to write a Bash script that checks and returns IDs of rows in CSV that fail certain criteria. A sample CSV is like below, I am thinking the [ -z {$CATEGORY} ] menthod to identify  null value cell in CATEGORY column of the CSV. However, it seem that my if statement is not catching the null value in the CSV, hence need help

```
ID,DATE,PRODUCT CODE,CATERGORY
1,01/01/2000,10009,1
2,02/01/2000,9999,2
3,25/01/2000,1009,3
4,15/09/2000,2001,5
5,09/25/2000,2003,4
6,09/10/01,2091,P
7,20/02/2002,3098,6
8,01/03/2003,4097,3
9,03/04/2004,5000,2
10,05/02/2013,4000,1
11,10/01/2015,9,
```

This is my bash script code, the null value is in the row with ID = 11

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=${1}
IFS=$'\n'
((c=-1))
for row in $(cat $FILE)
do
        ((c++))
        if ((c==0))
                then
                        continue
        fi
        IFS=','
        read ID DATE PRODUCT CATEGORY <<<${row}

                if [ -z {$CATEGORY} ];
                then
                     echo "$ID" >> file.txt
                fi
done
```

Comment: [Don't read lines with a `for` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- there are all sorts of weird things that can go wrong. Also, changing `IFS` (without restricting it to a specific command) can cause other weird problems.

Comment: If _CATEGORY_ is empty, `{$CATEGORY}` expands to `{}` which is not a null-string. Therefore your query will always be true, unless when CATEGORY contains a space, in which case you will get a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-z {$CATEGORY}` should be `-z ${CATEGORY}`, but `read ID ... <<< ${row}` will assign only `ID`... Try:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r ID DATE PRODUCT CATEGORY; do
  if [[ "$CATEGORY" =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
    echo "$ID"
  fi
done < <( tail -n+2 "$1" ) > file.txt
```

Note that `awk` or `sed` would be much faster and simpler for this (see, for instance, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Example with `awk` (tested with recent BSD and GNU `awk`):

```bash
awk -F, 'NR>1 && $NF ~ /^[[:space:]]*$/ {print $1}' "$FILE" > file.txt
```

Example with `sed` (tested with recent BSD and GNU `sed`):

```bash
sed -En 's/^([^,]*).*,[[:space:]]*$/\1/p' "$FILE" > file.txt
```

Comment: Renaud thanks for your answer but your while loop solution isn't working. But will look at the awk or sed methods you suggest.

Comment: @ChanWeeHow What is not working? I just tested with your own example and it behaves as you want.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, I copied your while loop code and ran it but my file.txt is still empty.

Comment: Then you probably have spaces after the comma in your input file. Do you confirm? I updated my answer to also cover this case.